# Using Kalium on Server and libsodium.js on client

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, libsodium

Im a newbie trying out the NaCl wrappers. Im using Kalium on my server and libsodium.js  on my client end at each end they are working but when I try to use authenticated encryption to communicate between the 2 ends the ciphertext fails verification. 
Encryption on the client is done by:

```
var nonce=sodium.crypto_generichash(sodium.crypto_box_NONCEBYTES, dataObj.extensionId);
var message="test";
var encryptedString = sodium.crypto_box_easy(message, nonce, serverPublicKeyBytes, clientPrivateKey);
```

the nonce,serverPublicKeyBytes and clientPrivateKey are transferred as Base64 Strings to the server.

In the server the data is decrypted using:

```
public byte[] decrypt( byte[] publicKey, byte[] privateKey, byte[] nonce,
            byte[] message) throws Exception {
        Box box = new Box(publicKey, privateKey);
        byte[] output= box.decrypt(nonce, message);

        return output;
    }
```

In the server the wrapper uses the java byte[] while on the server the javascript uses UInt8Array[], can someone assist me in enabling client-server communication.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After more trial and error I found out that the default Box class in kalium does not work with the javascript version of `sodium.crypto_box_easy` ...

Clone the kalium project to your environment and add the following code to the class NaCl:

```
public int crypto_box_easy(@Out byte[] ciphertext, @In byte[] plaintext, @In @u_int64_t int plaintextLength,
                @In byte[] nonce, @In byte[] receiverPublicKey, @In byte[] senderPrivateKey);

        public int crypto_box_open_easy(@Out byte[] plaintext, @In byte[] ciphertext,
                @In @u_int64_t int ciphertextLength, @In byte[] nonce, @In byte[] senderPublicKey,
                @In byte[] receiverPrivateKey);
```

And then call this code in either the Box class or create your own class :

```
isValid(sodium().crypto_box_easy(ciphertext, plaintext, plaintext.length, nonce, receiverPublicKey,
                senderPrivateKey), "Encryption failed");
isValid(sodium().crypto_box_open_easy(plaintext, ciphertext, ciphertext.length, nonce, senderPublicKey,
            receiverPrivateKey), "Decryption failed. Ciphertext failed verification.");
```

The ciphertext in the above code (crypto_box_easy) is a new byte[] object with **the length = crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305_MACBYTES(16) + plaintext** length.
The plaintext in the above code (crypto_box_open_easy) is a new byte[] object whose length is the **length of the original plaintext**.